# characteristic function of a convolution of measures

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, convolution, characteristic-functions

Take the probability measures $\mu,\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and denote $\varphi_{\mu}$ (the same for $\nu$) its characteristic function. Why holds
$$\varphi_{\mu *\nu}(t)=\varphi_{\mu}(t)\cdot\varphi_{\nu}(t)$$
where $\mu*\nu$ denotes the convolution of $\mu$ and $\nu$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer in the case where the probability densities exist.  Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be the given densities and $h(x)$ the result of the convolution.

$h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-u)g(u)du$.  Then $\phi_h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)e^{itx}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itx}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-u)g(u)dudx$

Change order of integration and let $y=x-u$ to get $\phi_h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(u)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it(y+u)}f(y)dydu=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(u)e^{itu}du\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ity}f(y)dy=\phi_g(t)\phi_f(t)$.

Using Stieljtes integrals, the proof can be used for distribution functions.

Comment: My problem is, that i have to prove this for the generel case, so i cannot assume that densities exist. My main problem:
If we have $X,Y$ independent random variables with laws $\mu,\nu$ and $\mathcal{L}(X+Y)$ the law of the sum, then why holds $$\mu *\nu=\mathcal{L}(X+Y)?$$

Comment: Proof for characteristic function:  $X$ and $Y$ are independent, therefore:                          
             $ϕ_{X+Y}(t)=E(e^{it(X+Y)})=E(e^{itX}e^{itY})=E(e^{itX})E(e^{itY})=ϕ_X(t)ϕ_Y(t)$ .

Answer (score 1):

Neither do we need to assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ admit densities with respect to a common reference measure, nor do we need to restrict this result to $\mathbb R$.

Remember that if $(E,\mathcal E)$ is a measurable group and $$\tau:E^2\to E\;,\;\;\;(x,y)\mapsto xy$$ denotes the group operation, then $\mu\ast\nu$ is the pushforward $\tau(\mu\otimes\nu)$ of the product measure $\mu\otimes\nu$ under $\tau$.

Assuming that $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space (consider as a group with the group operation being the addition) and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$, we immediately obtain \begin{equation}\begin{split}\varphi_{\mu\ast\nu}(x')&=\int\tau(\mu\otimes\nu)({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:x\rangle}\\&=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int\nu({\rm d}y)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:\tau(x,\:y)\rangle}\\&=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:x\rangle}\int\nu({\rm d}y)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:y\rangle}=\varphi_\mu(x')\varphi_\nu(x')\end{split}\tag1\end{equation} for all $x'\in E'$.