# Verifying fundamental property of convolution of measures

Tags: calculus, probability, measure-theory

One property of the characteristic function $\phi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx}\mu(dx)$ is that for measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ with respective $\phi_1(t)$ and $\phi_2(t)$, the convolved measure $\mu_1\ast\mu_2$ has $\phi_1(t)\phi_2(t)$. It suffices to observe that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it(x+y)}\mu_1(dy)\mu_2(dx)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itz}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu_1(dz-x)\mu_2(dx)$$ which intuitively makes sense to me. However, I am unsure of the exact mechanics to get from the LHS to the RHS (or is the direct equality self-justifiable?). Perhaps my calculus is still weak, so any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Clearly, a change of variables $z=x+y$ should yield:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itz}\mu_1(dz-x)\mu_2(dx)$$ then it remains to do an integral switch.

**Edit 2:**

I'll include below the answer by @0xbadf00d, linked by @FShrike:

Remember that if $(E,\mathcal E)$ is a measurable group and $$\tau:E^2\to E\;,\;\;\;(x,y)\mapsto xy$$ denotes the group operation, then $\mu\ast\nu$ is the pushforward $\tau(\mu\otimes\nu)$ of the product measure $\mu\otimes\nu$ under $\tau$.

Assuming that $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space (consider as a group with the group operation being the addition) and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$, we immediately obtain \begin{equation}\begin{split}\varphi_{\mu\ast\nu}(x')&=\int\tau(\mu\otimes\nu)({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:x\rangle}\\&=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int\nu({\rm d}y)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:\tau(x,\:y)\rangle}\\&=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:x\rangle}\int\nu({\rm d}y)e^{{\rm }i\langle x',\:y\rangle}=\varphi_\mu(x')\varphi_\nu(x')\end{split}\tag1\end{equation} for all $x'\in E'$.

I'm quite unfamiliar with this approach so I'll expand upon this later when I have the time.

Comment: I really don't like "$\mu_1(dz-x)$". But this has been asked, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3878491). Fubini's theorem of interchange applies as everything is absolutely integrable (to $1$)

Comment: Thank you! The link above contains a direct proof assuming existence of densities and another one using characteristic functions which were both helpful, I'll think a bit more about the general case using only measures

Comment: The answer I linked IS a proof using only measures, no assumptions of density. It just finds the correct formalism with which to view the convolution $\mu_1\ast\mu_2$

Comment: Yes, I am indeed referring to that as the one I have to think about, as well as the two earlier ones in that thread